# Visual Studio 2005 build problem

Tags: visual-studio-2005, build-process, build

I have a project Y whose build order properties states it depends on project X. I need to map project X's dll within Project  Y References folder.

The problem arises when the dll for Project X is not mapped within Project Y References folder. Then when I build Project Y it fails with because it can't find the reference to Project X.

I then manually copy the Project X's dll (observing the timestamp) into Project Y bin folder and remap the Project X dll with Project Y references folder.

This manual hack works though does anyone know how to get the project to its previous state when it was automatically building project X dll and referencing it within Project Y?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If both projects are in the same solution you can use project references instead of referencing the dll's.

If they are not in the same solution you could copy the dll's in a post build script.